# Override Apple's cURL with Homebrew's cURL?

Tags: curl, osx-mavericks

Mavericks is creating certain SSL issues with my enterprise server. Hence, I need to override Apple's version of cURL (v7.30.0) to Homebrew cURL (v7.33.0).

What environment variables need to be set to do this.

Note: adding   export PATH = “ /usr/local/Cellar/curl/7.33.0/bin/:$PATH” to my bash_profile disables all commands recognised by bash.

Comment: Is that literally what you are setting `$PATH` to?  Looks there are spaces and you don't need the quotes.  Anyway what's this got to do with programming?  It looks like a simple user-level problem to me.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same requirement (although for a different reason). All I did was install the latest version of homebrew cURL (at this time = 7.51.0).

Then I just symlinked it to /usr/local/bin/curl:

```
ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/curl/7.51.0/bin/curl curl
```

For me, my $PATH variable has /usr/local/bin preceeding /usr/bin ... so it works for me.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

CURL on Mavericks now uses the certificates stored in Key Chain.

If you visit the HTTPS URL of your enterprise server using Safari you should see an SSL error. You can then choose to trust the SSL certificate and add it to your Key Chain. After this CURL should work correctly.